# Cannot make https request on esp32

Tags: esp32

I have esp32 cam. I want to send https request to azure function. I have exposed https port via ngrok.

```
HTTPClient http;

if (http.begin("https://4b21-31-183-241-151.eu.ngrok.io/", rootCACertificate)) { //Specify the URL and certificate
  int httpCode = http.GET();                                                  //Make the request

  if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code

      String payload = http.getString();
      Serial.println(httpCode);
      Serial.println(payload);
    }

  else {
    Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
  }

  http.end(); //Free the resources
} else {
  Serial.println("Cannot begin");
}
```

I have generated cert as `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 4b21-31-183-241-151.eu.ngrok.io`

http.begin returns 1, but http.GET() returns -1.

I want to do it with minimal effort. I saw that HttpClient allows https, so I don't need explicitly init WiFiClientSecure.

What I'm doing wrong?